# Are there practical results in engineering which rely on multiplication by 0?

Tags: arithmetic

If we take the meaning of multiplication seriously then:

$$3 \times 4 = 3 + 3 + 3 + 3$$

That is to say, we take the multiplicand and add itself to it the same number of times as the multiplier.  (Above $3$ is the multiplicand and $4$ is the multiplier).  Hence,

$$4 \times 3 = 4 + 4 + 4$$

So let's say that we take $0 \times 4$, this would be equivalent to:

$0 + 0 + 0 + 0$ which is still zero.  However, what would $4 \times 0$ be?  That would mean that you take $4$ and add $4$ to it zero times, which would still give you $4$.  It seems to me that the result of $4\times 0$ is a matter of deciding what $4$, $0$, multiplication and addition means and then being consistent.

---

Edit

We prove things in math not by replacing mathematical terms with their definitions and then using statement logic and seeing if the negation leads to a contradiction, it would be nice if we did do that, but no one can do that now, instead we are stuck with simply using the formulas over and over again and if they give us the results we want then we keep using them.  For example, with the quadratic equation we can plug the values into the equation and see if we get the result which matches the other side of the equation.  If we want to measure the volume of a complex shape we can pour liquid into a straight cylinder where we know the area and pour the liquid into the complex container to prove our results. The multiplication by zero however has very limited applicability.  In fact it seems to have no applicability. So the only way to test the if 4*0=0 is to use statement logic and employ a consistent usage of the terms involved.  So what I'm asking is if anyone knows of any applications of 4*0 to the real world?

Comment: Let's say you need to estimate the cost of fitting highway reflectors (cat's eyes) in the road over the bridge. If each reflector costs $\$50$ to fit, how much does it cost not to fit reflectors? Your calculation would give $\$50$.

Comment: "That would mean that you take 4 and add 4 to it zero times, which would still give you 4." By that reasoning, $4 \times 3$ means you take 4 and add 4 to it 3 times, which would be $4 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 16$.

Comment: I like to think of multiplication as meaning "of". So 4 x 0 means "4 of 0", which is just 0.

Comment: @littleO, right of course, but his problem is with “0 of 4”.

Comment: This doesn't strike me as a mathematical question. We can talk about the practical and intuitive meaning of multiplication by zero and derive its result from other axioms. There is an underlying mathematical question here, but "Show me a result in practical engineering" is not it.

Comment: How much is $4\times\pi$? And all engineering problems require a expression to be multiplied by 0 and the result be 0. Otherwise 0 would not be equal to 0 and we would have some problems...

Comment: "0 of 4" doesn't mean you have a 4 and just don't add other 4s to it--it means you have _no_ 4s. No fours at all leaves you with nothing, that is, zero.

Answer (score 5):

It is very popular to model concepts and procedures in science and engineering using **sparse** matrices today. A sparse matrix is a stencil of numbers which contains almost only the value $0$ and very few (maybe just one in thousand or one in a million non-zero values). When computing things with sparse matrices very many of the operations will be additions with $0$ and multiplications with $0$. So if the computer knows it can skip doing these operations (because they make no difference) then we can do the computations much faster!

Comment: I think this is a clever answer to a mediocre question. Nice

Comment: Nice answer: but the OP thinks that $4 \times 0$ should be $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Where has the logic failed? Operate it backwards.

4 added to itself to itself ( twice) makes  $ 4 + 4 + 4 =12 $

4 added to itself (once)  makes  $ 4 + 4  = 8 $

Leave alone 4 to itself ( null times) makes nothing new, $ 4 = 4 $

4 negatively added to itself ( once)  backwards leaves a new, $ 4 -4 = 0 $